# How to get query a certain period of datetime in Flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In Flask, I have a model named User, like this:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    post_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), index=True, default=datetime.now)
```

I wanna query a certain period datetime, for example, I need to query all the posts posted between `2016-11-01` and `2016-11-30`

I tried to achieve this by Stitching string, like this:

```
posts = Post.query.filter(Post.post_time <= year_month+'-30').filter(Post.post_time >= year_month+'-01')
```

but this is awkward, is there any better way to to that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `datetime.date` module:

```
from datetime import date

start = date(year=2016,month=11,day=1)
end = date(year=2016,month=11,day=30)

posts = Post.query.filter(Post.post_time <= end).filter(Post.post_time >= start)
```

[datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)